# Oracle DBMS_SCHEDULER.create_job with OUT parameter call

Tags: sql, oracle, plsql, oracle12c

Env: Oracle 12c

Unsure of the following and require confirmation.

If I call a job_type PLSQL_BLOCK scheduled job that will execute from systdate + 30 secs that has an OUT parameter, I assume after the scheduled job has completed, I will then have access to the OUT param value, i.e. `v_status` - is this correct based on below code example?

Just unsure when it comes to scheduled jobs.

```
create or replace package body my_package as

  procedure get_status ( in_curr_id    in      number,
                         o_status      out     varchar2 ) is

  begin
    select status 
    into o_status 
    from my_status_table 
    where curr_id = in_curr_id;
  end get_status;


  procedure process_task is

    v_plsql   varchar2(4000) := null;
    v_status  varchar2(10)   := null;
    v_curr_id number;
  begin
    v_curr_id := 100;
    v_plsql := 'begin get_status (in_curr_id => ' || v_curr_id || ',
                                  o_status   => ' || v_status  || '); end;'
    dbms_scheduler.create_job(job_name   => 'my_scheduled_job', 
                              job_type   => 'PLSQL_BLOCK', 
                              job_action => v_plsql,
                              start_date => sysdate + NUMTODSINTERVAL(30, 'SECOND'), 
                              enabled    => true);
    if v_status = 'OK' then
      -- do required processing
    else
      dbms_output.put_line(v_status);
  end process_task;

end my_package;
/
```

Comment: Your code is erroneous. `o_status` requires the variable name  and not the value. Your job will execute with failures. Also, `create job` doesnt set `o_status`

Comment: @Tejash - appreciate your response but could you pls let me know what I have done in error - perhaps correct my code as the bottom line is to determine if I have access to the OUT param value, from the returned scheduled job call.

Comment: Ok. So simply, no you do not have access to the out parameter of schedule job. But yes one way is to do not use out parameter, instead put it in some table and use it. But also note that creating the job and execution of that job is two different things. Why you want the out parameter in the same procedure? You can just query the table where you will put the values as suggested.

Comment: @Tejash - sorry, so that I understand exactly what you mean, could you pls demonstrate using my code. I basically need to determine what the status is within `my_status_table` for `v_curr_id` from systimestamp + 30 secs. I will update the start_date above.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As @Tejash points out there is nothing built into DBMS_SCHEDULER that will store values of out arguments in your block. You need to do it yourself.

Change this:

```
v_plsql := 'begin get_status (in_curr_id => ' || v_curr_id || ',
                              o_status   => ' || v_status  || '); end;'
```

to this:

```
v_plsql := 'declare s my_status_table.status%TYPE;
            begin get_status (in_curr_id => ' || v_curr_id || ',
                              o_status   => s); 
                  insert into my_status_table (curr_id, status)
                     values (' || v_curr_id || ', s);
                  commit;
            end;';
```

Comment: Great - really appreciate your response Steven, that makes it a lot more clearer now.