# Menage return of object from procedure called throgh DBMS_SCHEDULER.create_job

Tags: oracle, dbms-scheduler

I call a procedure with DBMS_SCHEDULER.create_job.
My procedure as output parameter has one object. How can i manage this object?

```
DBMS_SCHEDULER.create_job (
     job_name     => 'EXAMPLE_JOB',
     job_type     => 'PLSQL_BLOCK',
     job_action   => 'BEGIN DBMS_SCHEDULER.run_program
                     (program_name =>''EXAMPLE_PROG ''); END;',
     start_date   => SYSTIMESTAMP,
     enabled      => TRUE
)
```

The procedure EXAMPLE_PROG has one object as output parameter. How can i manage the object of return after the DBMS_SCHEDULER.create_job? I need to insert the resul on one table

Comment: The point of asynchronous job execution is to be asynchronous - the scheduling process is decoupled from it, so can't receive output. If you do have a good reason for using the job engine at all, you will need to record any output to a table of your design which you can then query later. Also, we don't create a job to run a job like that... the job action should be a `BEGIN example_prog; END;` block or the name of a procedure with `job_type` changed to  `STORED_PROCEDURE`. You can define arguments for input, but not for output.

Comment: I know, you're right. But, check this one : https://stackoverflow.com/questions/61569729/oracle-dbms-scheduler-create-job-with-out-parameter-call anyway, thanks for the comment!

Answer (score 0):

You have to do exactly what is described in the answer to the question you pointed ([Oracle DBMS_SCHEDULER.create_job with OUT parameter call](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/61569729/oracle-dbms-scheduler-create-job-with-out-parameter-call)).
Your PLSQL block should be a very usual complete PLSQL block:

- declare local variables
- call the `EXAMPLE_PROG` with the in and out parameters
- use the out parameters to insert a row in your table and `COMMIT`

You can write it and test it independently from the scheduling part.

Once it works as expected, then use this PLSQL block to create the job: put it into the `job_action`.